# Flutter:Remove all routes without route name

Tags: android, dart, flutter

In the project, I have done routing without giving the name to the screen just switching screen like  `Login()` everywhere but when I want to log out and want to clear the stack of the screen then how can I pop all screen? and I have not mentioned screen name while routing.

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()),);
```

I tried to pop all screen until I reach to the login screen but unable to switch because `'/login'` is not used for routing.

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil('/login', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

Comment: `NavigatorState#popUntil()` method takes only one parameter: `RoutePredicate predicate`

Comment: @pskink yes but in the predicate, we will have to use the screen name.

Comment: @pskink then what will be the route? How can predicate route without naming [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/popUntil.html) name is used.

Comment: so why dont you use "named" routes?

Comment: @pskink I'm a newbie to flutter I have used a simple way to navigate now I'm giving the name to all route and thanks.

Answer (score 3):

When you open the `Login()` , you could do something like this:

```
 Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Login(),
                settings: RouteSettings(name: '/login')),
          );
```

You should add a setting when pushing your route; with a custom name. If not using fixed route name.

And when you want to go back from to `Login()` :

```
 Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName("/login"));
```

Comment: i did but it is showing error ` The following StateError was thrown while handling a gesture: Bad state: Future already completed` .

Comment: I have to change every where ?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code , but seems your `login()` gets pop out of `navigation` stack in between screens before calling `.popUntil`

Comment: my login screen design starts with `WillPopScope` it may creates the problem.

Comment: Are you doing `pushreplacement` in after login screen? if yes then you are basically replacing the route name - `'/login'` with the new screen.

Comment: in splash used `pushreplacement`, in the login use `push`  to go for dashboard and on dashboard to account page used `push` and dialog appears for asking logout.

Comment: in `pushreplacement` do - `Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => Login(),
                  settings: RouteSettings(name: '/login'),
                ),
              );`